# Library compiled to architecture x64 with error in Arm architecture

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, arm

I'm developing a `C++` library that has a piece of `shell script` code that return the name of a specific serial port. When I run this script in console either X64 desktop or Arm enviorment the script returns the right answer. My problem ocur when  I execute the same script inside of the library, the returns shows bad formed string like `ÈÛT¶ÈÛT¶¨a`  , but the expected is `/dev/ttyACM0`.

The script that run inside of library:

**Script**

```
bash -c 'for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev);do(syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}";devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)";[[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]]&& continue;teste="$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath | grep -i "company_name")";if [[ !  -z "${teste// }" && $devname == *"ttyACM"* ]]; then echo "/dev/$devname";fi);done;' 2> /dev/null
```

The following piece of code is used to save the content returned by the script into a file.

**code c++**

```
pfFile = fopen(CONFIG_FILE, "w+");
fwrite(result,strlen(result), 1, pfFile);
fclose(pfFile);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides you didn't include what is result and where it comes from in your C++ code; you selected the hardest way to do this. Code running shell scripts inside a library most likely cause nothing but headaches.

Basically you can create an `udev` rule for your device to create an unique and stable file in /dev to access it. You can create one like [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Writing_udev_rules) in the ArchWiki

```
KERNEL=="video[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4519", SYMLINK+="video-cam1"
```

Comment: I can't make rules in `udev`, because this library is used to our costumers.

Comment: So, there's another way. Save your script as a file beside your executable output. Using `/proc/self` you can access the executable's path and execute the shell script there. You can check the output of the shell script on ssh or serial console for debugging purposes. Even you can output it to a file